# Custom permalink structure for posts in specific category

Tags: permalinks

Hi I'm trying to rewrite permalink structure for posts in one specific category, the structure should be category name - author name - post title
When I use the code below, there is no author name in the URL
Please, advise me where am I wrong.

```
add_filter( 'post_link', 'custom_permalink', 'author_link', 10, 3 );
function custom_permalink( $permalink, $post, $leavename ) {
// Get the category for the post
$category = get_the_category($post->ID);
if (  !empty($category) && $category[0]->cat_name == "Tips" ) {
    $cat_name = strtolower($category[0]->cat_name);
    $author_nickname = get_user_meta( $author_id, 'nickname', true );
    $permalink = trailingslashit( home_url('/'. $cat_name . '/' . 
$author_nickname . '/' . $post->post_name .'/' ) );
}
return $permalink;
}

add_filter( 'category_link', 'custom_category_permalink', 10, 2 );
function custom_category_permalink( $link, $cat_id ) {
$slug = get_term_field( 'slug', $cat_id, 'category' );
if ( ! is_wp_error( $slug ) && 'tips' === $slug ) {
    $link = home_url( user_trailingslashit( '/tips/', 'category' ) );
}
return $link;
}

add_action( 'init', 'custom_rewrite_rules' );
function custom_rewrite_rules() {
add_rewrite_rule(
    'tips(?:/page/?([0-9]{1,})|)/?$',
    'index.php?category_name=tips&paged=$matches[1]',
    'top' // The rule position; either 'top' or 'bottom' (default).
);

add_rewrite_rule(
'tips/\d+/([^/]+)(?:/([0-9]+))?/?$', // <- here, add the \d+/
'index.php?category_name=tips&name=$matches[1]&page=$matches[2]',
'top'
);
}
```

Comment: I see you use `$category[0]`, what if the post is in the category but it's `$category[1]` or `$category[4]`? Note that nicknames can be changed in the admin interface so they aren't good for use in URLs. Also, when you say there is no author in the URL can you be more specific? Do you mean links to that post have the wrong URL? You get the wrong canonical URL? Redirects? It's unclear. Can you fix the indenting on your code?

Comment: Yes, the author nickname doesn't appear in the URL. Thank you for noticing the category id.

Comment: Is it possible to use author slug instead of nickname? The slug which remains unchanged if the nickname is changed? Slug of Usernames which cannot be changed

Comment: I changed author to $author = get_the_author_meta( 'user_url', $user_id, true ); But still no author slug in the permalink structure

Answer (score 0):

This code works good for me:

```
 add_filter( 'post_link', 'custom_permalink', 'author_link', 10, 3 );
 function custom_permalink( $permalink, $post, $leavename ) {
  // Get the category for the post
  $category = get_the_category($post->ID);
  if (  !empty($category) && $category[0]->cat_name == "Tips" ) {
    $cat_name = strtolower($category[0]->cat_name);
    $authordata = get_userdata( $post->post_author );
        $author     = $authordata->user_nicename;
    $permalink = trailingslashit( home_url('/'. $cat_name . '/' . $author . '/' .          
$post->post_name .'/' ) );
}
return $permalink;
}

add_filter( 'category_link', 'custom_category_permalink', 10, 2 );
function custom_category_permalink( $link, $cat_id ) {
$slug = get_term_field( 'slug', $cat_id, 'category' );
if ( ! is_wp_error( $slug ) && 'tips' === $slug ) {
    $link = home_url( user_trailingslashit( '/tips/', 'category' ) );
}
return $link;
}

add_action( 'init', 'custom_rewrite_rules' );
function custom_rewrite_rules() {
add_rewrite_rule(
    'tips(?:/page/?([0-9]{1,})|)/?$',
    'index.php?category_name=tips&paged=$matches[1]',
    'top' // The rule position; either 'top' or 'bottom' (default).
);

add_rewrite_rule(
'tips/\d+/([^/]+)(?:/([0-9]+))?/?$', // <- here, add the \d+/
'index.php?category_name=tips&name=$matches[1]&page=$matches[2]',
'top'
);
}
```

Comment: But I had another problem, with a category of Spanish name, the letter ó remains ó in the URL, however the category slug has regular "o" letter

Comment: In my case this changes the permalink structure, however I get 404 when visiting example.com/category/author/post-title. Also shouldn't the old permalink redirect to the new permalink, and shouldn't the new permalink structure apply to the sitemap as well?